# Reducing a 'player' count using an if statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script for a game where the user has to guess a computer generated value. The aim is for the player number to be reduced until it has a value of 1 at which point it ends.

```
import random 
import time

players = input("Let's play Five's! How many are you?:" )
#print("you are", players, "players?") #test number of players
players = int(players)


if players <=1:
    print("Game Over")

else:
    while players >= 1:
        players = players+1

#Decide possible values than can be chosen
        options = [] #Possible options
        for i in range(0,players):
            x = i * 5
            options.append(x)
        print("Your choices are", options)

#Playing the game
#Each turn
        guess = random.choice(options)
        print("Computer has chosen", int(guess))
        count_down = 3
        while (count_down):
            print(count_down)
            time.sleep(1)
            count_down -=  1
        choice = input("Guess:")
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice not in options: #If choice isn't a multiple of 5
            input("Not allowed, choose again:")
        elif choice in options and choice != guess: #Valid choice but wrong
                print("Wrong")                      #so player is still in the
        else:                                       #game
            choice = int(choice)
            if choice == guess: #Correct choice so player leaves game
                print("You're Out.") # this should reduce the player count
        players -=1
```

I've included the line printing the computer generated value so I can give the correct guess but even if guess correctly it doesn't reduce the player count and so the game continues infinitely

Comment: The first line in your loop adds one to `players`, and then the last line subtracts one.  As far as I can see, this loop can never exit, because those two actions cancel each other out.

Answer (score 0):

You add a player on the first line of the `while` loop.

```
players = players+1
```

Then you subtract a player on the last line

```
players -=1
```

If I understand your code correctly, the number of players won't change.